# Computation consideration with different Caffe's network topology (difference in number of output)

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I would like to use one of Caffe's reference model i.e. `bvlc_reference_caffenet`. I found that my target class i.e. person is one of the classes included in the ILSVRC dataset that has been trained for the model. As my goal is to classify whether a test image contains a person or not, I may achieve this by the following:

1. Use inference directly with 1000 number of output. This doesn't
   require training/learning.
2. Change the network topology a little bit with the final FC layer's number of output (`num_output`) is set to 2 (instead of 1000). Retrain it as a binary classification problem.

My concern is about computational effort at deployment/prediction phase (testing). The latter looks more expensive computationally than the former. This is because during prediction phase it needs to compute those 1000 output possibilities to find the one with the highest score. What I'm not sure is that, it could be the case that there's a heuristic (which I'm not aware of) that simplifies the computation.

Can somebody please help cross check my understanding on this.

Comment: If the result's quality from the `bvlc_reference_caffenet` is sufficient for your needs, let use the first method. Implementing the second one will not change a lot the computational time: you do not gain a lot in comparison to all the computation processed earlier in the net (convolutional layers) during the forward pass.

Comment: @xiawi: Yes, you are correct that I don't "gain a lot in comparison to all the computation processed earlier in the net (convolutional layers) during the forward pass", but I still have a little doubt that computing the class score with 1000 classes is having  a small difference computationally as opposed to 2 classes. If computing 1000 vs 990 classes might be having not much difference.

Comment: Perhaps, others can give their insight on this as well.